# I disabled mouse acceleration on my laptop, but now my mouse speed doesn't change

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have a Lenovo Y710 laptop that is running Ubuntu 16.04, my mouse is the Logitech marathon M705. I'm running a fresh boot and have been going over basic settings. This is my first time using Linux. I don't like mouse acceleration, as there is no option in the settings to disable it I found the below solution on the internet.

I typed:

> sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mouse.conf

into a terminal and ran the below code.

> Section "InputClass"
>       Identifier "mouse"
>       MatchIsPointer "on"
>       Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
>       Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
>   EndSection

I restarted, mouse acceleration was off, I could change the speed of the touchpad, but I could not change the speed of my physical mouse. The slider worked and moved from slow to fast, but the mouse speed remained static at a relatively slow speed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try your preferred setting whit this command:

```
 xinput set-prop 'mouse' 279 0.9
```

You can change the 0.9 to a value from 0.0 to 1.0 (higher is faster).

After you found your preferred setting, make it permanent by adding the a line like

```
 Option  "Accel Speed" "0.9"
```

to the config file you edited before. Place it directly before the line "EndSection".